# jQuery select partial text/chars and addClass or tag

Tags: jquery, tags, partial, addclass

How would one be able to select partial characters and add a class or add a tag to those characters/text using jQuery?

Here is code I have to play with:

```
<b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice">
     <font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:<br></b></font>
        $2,492.38
   </font>
</b>

<a class="pricecolor colors_productprice specialprice" href="javascript:void(0);">
<b><div id="emailprice">Click Here For Price!</div></b></a>
```

I want to make it something like this:

```
<font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price:<br></b></font>
    $2,492<sup>.38</sup>
```

Comment: Will the value be numerical all the time and you need superscript for something that's after decimal?

Comment: This is correct, it will be numerical all the time.  I have many products with prices from the $10,000.00 all the way down to around $1.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this work for you?..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pricecolor').html(
        $('.pricecolor').html().replace(/\.\d{1,2}/,
            function(a){
                return '<sup>' + a + '</sup>';
            })
    );
});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/Fe5Fb/)**

**Edit:**

Here's what the regex is doing:

- `\.` - look for a dot
- `\d{1,2}` followed by one or two digits

Obviously the *correct* format would be two digits after the dot in which case the expression should simply be `/\.\d{2}/`, but I've seen some strange formatting on some sites, so decided to include that :)

Comment: Could you explain briefly what '.replace(/\.\d[1,2]/' is doing?

Comment: @Demian-Brecht: I have another dilemma.  On a category page with multiple products, some products have two of the same font classes, I need it to only be on the first of the font class '.pricecolor' not the second one that appears for each 'td'. I will update question.

Comment: I have got it, I just need to add 'font.pricecolor'

Answer (score 1):

Two lines of code...

```
parts = $('.pricecolor').html().split('.');
$('font.pricecolor').html(parts[0]+".<sup>"+parts[1]+"</sup>");
```

Comment: +1: I always prefer non-regex solutions when regex is not *required*. Must be that I hadn't finished my first coffee of the day yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using some RegEx and replace() aplyed to innerHTML.